# How to install hpilo-exporter?

Tags: prometheus, exporter

so I'm trying to setup the hpilo-exporter for Prometheus to monitor the Power-Supply of one of our servers, but I'm struggling with the installation.

I tried following the steps mentioned in [Github](https://github.com/infinityworks/hpilo-exporter):

As mentioned there, I tried to run "pip install -e $HPILO_EXPORTER_DIR", which doesn't work for me (it's missing an argument for -e which would either be a vcs project url or a local project path, both of which I don't have?)

So I tried "pip install hpilo-exporter" which is also mentioned as a way to install the hpilo-exporter, which apparently is supposed to have worked ( I get following output after running the pip command "Installing collected packages: prometheus-client, python-hpilo, hpilo-exporter
Successfully installed hpilo-exporter-0.4.5 prometheus-client-0.15.0 python-hpilo-4.4.3") so I figured that it worked and tried to run the command to start the hpilo-exporter (as mentioned on GitHub aswell) which is "hpilo-exporter [--address=0.0.0.0 --port=9416 --endpoint="/metrics"]" but this isn't being recognised as a
command (output "hpilo-exporter: Command not found.")

So my question is, how do I solve this and get the hpilo-exporter to install and work properly?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

install python2 and pip2
set these as alias' to python and pip
follow hpilo-exporter github instructions, should work